# List returns none-type after creation in recursive loop for merge sort

Tags: python, algorithm, list, mergesort, nonetype

I am trying to understand algorithms by writing them myself. While trying to replicate merge sort I have run into some trouble: left & right return none-type and an error is raised for the len(left) in the first while loop. I have been fighting with the code and could not figure out what I was missing? Shouldn't it just loop until the size of left and right lists reduce to 1 which would allow them to get out of the if loop and continue with the next part of the function?

```
def merge_sort(A):

    if len(A) < 2:
        return A
    else:
        mid= len(A)//2
        left= merge_sort(A[:mid])
        right= merge_sort(A[mid:])

    i = j = 0
    sortedlist = []
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            sortedlist.append(left[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            sortedlist.append(right[j])
            j+=1
    while i < len(left):
        sortedlist.append(left[i])
        i+=1
    while j < len(right):
        sortedlist.append(right[j])
        j+=1
    print(str(sortedlist))
```

Comment: just need to sort out your indenting a little

Comment: Oh the indenting is fine normally, I don't know why it came out like this in the question. I'll edit it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is add a return statement (the last statement in the code below):

```
def merge_sort(A):

    if len(A) < 2:
        return A
    else:
        mid= len(A)//2
        left = merge_sort(A[:mid])
        right = merge_sort(A[mid:])

    i = j = 0
    sortedlist = []
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            sortedlist.append(left[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            sortedlist.append(right[j])
            j+=1
    while i < len(left):
        sortedlist.append(left[i])
        i+=1
    while j < len(right):
        sortedlist.append(right[j])
        j+=1

    # NEED TO RETURN THE LIST HERE!
    return sortedlist
```

if your function does not return anything statements like `left = merge_sort(A[:mid])` will assign `None` to `left` instead of the sorted (half of the) list.

you could then test that with:

```
import random

lst = list(range(15))
random.shuffle(lst)
ret = merge_sort(lst)
print(ret)
```

Comment: When I add the return statement, the function returns nothing, not even the error.

Comment: there is no print statement in the function. the function **does** return something; it's just that nothing is printed. added a snippet for how you could test your sort function.

Comment: The extra code you wrote works, but there is a print statement at the end of the function, any idea why it does not work by itself?

Comment: in the function in my answer there is no print statement... is yours after the return statement? in that case it would never get executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't contain a return statement. You should add `return sortedlist` at it's end.

Comment: Added the return statement but the function does not return anything.

Comment: Does it print the list?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't even print the list.